# Data dumps for specific sites

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

Is there a way to download a data dump for specific sites in the Stack Exchange network?

The cumulative data dump is pretty large, and I am only really interested in the data dumps for a couple of sites, [Skeptics.se](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/about) and [EL&U.se](https://english.stackexchange.com/about).

Is that currently possible?

Comment: You won't be able to download a Skeptics data dump as the site is not out of beta yet.

Comment: @Fabian Now it is.

Answer (score 12):

If you [download the data dumps using the clear-bits torrent](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/) you can then specify certain files not to download  in most torrent clients. The skeptics data dump wasn't in the torrent I used as an example...but presumably will be the latest (provided it is out of beta).

[image]